# Calculate mathematical series with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I need to calculate a mathematical series in a Postgresql select statement and add the result as a column called  "total_days".The formula is

[image]

The variable *insts* comes from the SQL table itself. Is it possible to calculate without using PL/SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can pull the 30 out of your sum, and use the closed form solution for the sum `30 * (1 + 2 + 3 + .... + insts) = 30 * insts * (insts + 1) / 2` [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

If you have a series that doesn't have a closed form, you can still do this in SQL like so:

```
SELECT
  my_table.insts,
  (
    SELECT SUM(i*30)
    FROM generate_series(1, insts) AS xs(i)
  ) as "sum"
FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is essentially 30 * (sum of numbers 1..n).

The formula for the sum of numbers, starting at 1 to n is: n*(n+1)/2.

So the SQL select statement is:

```
select 30*insts*(insts+1)/2 from YOUR_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
create temp table vals ( val integer);
insert into vals (val) values (1), (2), (3);

select val, sum(x)
from (select val, generate_series(1,val)*30 as x from vals) as y
group by val;
```